# Giving minimal rights to 3rd party to do reporting

Tags: 2010, permissions

We are planning to integrate the reporting of our sharepoint 2010 environment into our standard reporting platform that is managed by a 3rd party. The reporting requirements go as deep as possible, like report properties in every file in a document library. Of course I would like to give as less permission as possible to our 3rd party to create the solution. Is it possible to set a permission level that makes the team to read details about files in a document library like size, upload date etc., but not able to open the document itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if they can read the metadata about an Item (the Document is contained within the Item), they'll be able to open the document itself. But in this case, I'd suggest providing Full Read access on the User Policy of the Web Application.

Comment: Essentially the same permission you'd give your search service account

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you, not possible is also an answer. Then we are looking for other solutions.